# When can ValidatorUtils.getValueAsString() return null?

Tags: java, apache-commons

In our code we are using ValidatorUtils.getValueAsString() to get a value as string from a bean. It returned null for us during code execution.

Below description I found for the method in Apache doc:

> ```
> public static String getValueAsString(Object bean,
>                       String property)
> ```
>
> Convenience method for getting a value from a bean property as a `String`. If the property is a `String[]` or `Collection` and it is empty, an empty `String ""` is returned. Otherwise, `property.toString()` is returned. This method may return null if there was an error retrieving the property.

What scenarios can cause an error in retrieving the property?

Answer (score 0):

The method returns null if an error occurs in the `PropertyUtils.getProperty(bean, property)` used inside.

And the [Javadocs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-) says that an error occurs if:

1. `bean`or `proeprty` is `null`
2. `bean` does not contains an accessible field or accessor method for `property`
3. an error occurred calling the accessor inside `bean`